# PHP switches for text-based game

Tags: php, switch-statement, conditional-statements

So I have an idea for a game that I want to develop for a small group of online friends and I'm actually pretty far into the html and css as well as some of the javascript/jquery. What I'm wanting advice on is if this sample of the basic framework will be functional enough to allow me to go ahead with this idea or if I should change something extensively. I'm new to PHP but I know I need a server-side language to make the game more dynamic and keep them from perusing the code to get answers...

So is a text-based game viable using this simple framework as a starting point or should I be using something entirely different?

EDIT: The game is progressive so they don't need access to the previous levels once they reach the next one. The results of the check will be transferred through Ajax/Jquery to a simulated console for them to view it in real-time.

```
<?php
session_start();

//Text sent through jquery and ajax, checked for a passcode to access a higher level directly since I'm using sessions

switch($_POST['text']){
case a:
    $_SESSION['auth_level'] = 2;
    break;
case b:
    $_SESSION['auth_level'] = 3;
    break;
case c:
    $_SESSION['auth_level'] = 4;
    break;
case d:
    $_SESSION['auth_level'] = 5;
    break;
case e:
    $_SESSION['auth_level'] = 6;
    break;
default:
    $_SESSION['auth_level'] = 1;
    break;
};

//Giving them conditional access to commands based on their authorization level

if($_SESSION['auth_level'] = 1) {
switch($_POST['text']){
    case a:
    echo "";
    break;
case b:
    echo "";
    break;
case c:
    echo "";
    break;
case d:
    echo "";
    break;
case e:
    echo "";
    break;
case f:
    echo "You are now authorized for level 2!";
    $_SESSION['auth_level'] = 2;
    break;
}

elseif($_SESSION['auth_level'] = 2) {
switch($_POST['text']){
    case a:
    echo "";
    break;
case b:
    echo "";
    break;
case c:
    echo "";
    break;
case d:
    echo "";
    break;
case e:
    echo "";
    break;
case f:
    echo "You are now authorized for level 3!";
    $_SESSION['auth_level'] = 3;
    break;
}

elseif($_SESSION['auth_level'] = 3) {
switch($_POST['text']){
    case a:
    echo "";
    break;
case b:
    echo "";
    break;
case c:
    echo "";
    break;
case d:
    echo "";
    break;
case e:
    echo "";
    break;
case f:
    echo "You are now authorized for level 4!";
    $_SESSION['auth_level'] = 4;
    break;
}

//For anything not designated as a command

else {
echo $_POST['text'] . " is not a valid command or access code"
?>
```

Comment: You're writing a lot of things more than once, you can do things like `case 'a': case 'b': case 'c': // do stuff; break;`.

Comment: However... can you tell us more about how you want the code to behave? Right now you're posting something called 'text' over to your script but then your logic means that it will first send them through the 'auth level' bit and set their auth level, but then it will automatically test the 'auth level' and give them authorisation to particular bits. It doesn't quite make sense. For example, `$_POST['text']` is blank, it will give them `auth_level=1`, then it will immediately give them `auth_level=2`

Comment: @AdamW Oh, no I see what you mean with the default. Sorry, that was sloppy copy/paste. Changed the defaults to case f. Would it default out of the switch if none matched and go to the last else statement in the code or should I define a default for each one?

Comment: See my comment below, but if there is no default defined, it won't do anything. It's sane to write one if you need a specific action (`exit()` comes to mind) but it wouldn't be a huge deal for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got a little long for a comment so I'll try and help.

Ideally if you're trying to implement a text-based game where users enter commands, or they enter a level code, you should consider splitting them into two different fields - something like `$_POST['level_code']` which would be different from their 'command'.

```
session_start();

// If a user doesn't have an auth_level, give them the default
if(!isset($_SESSION['auth_level'])) {
    $_SESSION['auth_level'] = 1;
}

// If a user posts a level code, do something with it
if(isset($_POST['level_code']) {
    switch ($_POST['level_code']) {
        case 'levelcode_a':
            // Give your user feedback as well if you want
            $_SESSION['auth_level'] = 1;
            break;
        case 'levelcode_b':
            $_SESSION['auth_level'] = 2;
            break;
            // etc, etc
        case 'levelcode_c':
        default:
            // User didn't send a level code so don't do anything
    }
}

if (!isset($_POST['text'])) {
    exit("No additional codes were given");
}

// Then do your application logic
switch ($_SESSION['auth_level']) {
    case 1:
        switch ($_POST['text']) {
            case 'a':
                // Some game activity
                break;
            case 'b':
                // Some game activity
                break;
        }
        // Enable level 1 actions
        break;
    case 2:
        // Enable level 2 actions
        break;
    default:
        // Don't do anything

}
```

So essentially it's a switch within a switch if you just want to create a single monolithic script that handles all your game activity.

There are other patterns, but this is relatively easy to keep your head around. I would more than likely pass secondary `switch`es over to a function so you can build something like `do_level_1_action(user_input)` if they're level 1 and so on, it might help separate the logic a bit for you.

Comment: Monolithic sounds fine for me since this is my first php and it's the easiest way to wrap my head around it at this point. So far, you've been a great help though. The code doesn't have to be extremely versatile as long as they can return to levels they've reached.

Comment: You're welcome - there are other things I'd do if you were making something more robust, ideally you'd split the game options and content into a different file, perhaps parse some XML and that way it's easy to separate the content from the game logic, but it's a little excessive for a hobby game!

Comment: Yeah. I'll save more complex stuff for later. For now, I'm amused that everything so far is functional and I just need to implement the ajax and php scripts before finishing the text.

Comment: `$.ajax('your_php_script.php', { data: { text: 'whatever_the_value_of_your_textbox_is' }, success: function (data) { alert(data) //alert with whatever your php script said, error: function() { //If you get here your PHP script failed or there was an HTTP error or something  }; } });`

Comment: Ahh, that was unnecessary helpfulness but I'll file it away for later use. I'm a complete Ajax novice so all the information I can get helps. :)

Comment: Syntax errors in it be damned :P

Comment: I don't even want to think about that. I have used JSLint so much when learning new JavaScript just because I miss semicolons or a quotation mark. That's about where the usefulness ends though...anyway, I'm told not to discuss here so I'll hush. :)